# Unmapping memory-mapped images that are created during processing

Tags: memory, ffmpeg, indexing, mapping, png

I have a pretty big issue, although I only have the symptoms, and a theory on the cause.

I have a C++ application under Windows 7x64 that uses system calls to FFMPEG 0.7.13 to extract frames from videos. When running, the parent application maintains a nice, predicable memory footprint in memory profilers (task manager, RAMMap) of about 2MB. I can see the individual calls to FFMPEG also come and go without incident. The trouble is, after about 100 calls to FFMPEG, and 70,000+ PNGs created (no one directory has more than 1500 pngs), the Windows memory page size raises gradually from about 2.5GB to over 7.0GB, and the system is brought to its knees. The sum of the processes for all users is no where near the reported Memory Page amount.

I thought it might be Windows Search indexing related, so I turned off the indexing for the output directories in question using SetFileAttributes() and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED, and while it seems to be working as advertised, it does not seem to combat the issue at hand. My current running theory is that all of these extracted PNGs are either fully or partially memory mapped, by FFMPEG or something else. I can also see the output PNGs under the RAMMap Physical Pages tab as standby mapped files.

Question:
- Is there enough information here to possibly diagnose the exact problem?
- Do I have a way to combat this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just to confirm, so your parent process is invoking ffmpeg to extract a single frame out of a video file? Also, have you tried using Process Explorer ...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 ... it has lots of good features to track memory usage, cpu usage or even check if there are any outstanding ffmpeg processes sticking around.

Comment: The process is invoking ffmpeg to extract all frames of a video into a unique destination directory. This can range anywhere from 200 to 1500 frames, depending on the video length. I can look into the link you provided, but I have already used several profilers, and the missing memory just does not seem to be related to a process. Smells like something a little more complicated than that, as alluded to by the RAMMap png physical page listings.

Comment: Just ran process explorer (wow, that is a nice presentation of processes and resources!), but it looks like it is illustrating the same picture. Parent runs stably with no leaks, and child ffmpegs are launched and exit, releasing the required memory. However the task manager mem page amount continues to grow unbounded, by (I'm now convinced) simply the creation and existence of the output PNGs.

Comment: If you just run an instance of ffmpeg on the command line without your parent process with the same command line; do you still see the increase in virtual memory observed above?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. A little difficult to run, as it takes several thousand PNGs to see any affect, but I wrapped commands in a BAT file mimicking the workflow, including the PNG extraction to a temp area, and then a copy to the final destination dir, and a final removal of the temp area (some renaming needs to happen between extraction and final resting place), and the mem page creep is *not* evident. So I am a little confused as to what the difference is. I guess I will have to poke around some more...

Comment: Another possibly interesting data point. After running for about 45 minutes, the mem page is physically 4.6GB, but process explorer indicates that there are almost 3.5GB for "standby" paging lists, and this amount continuously grows. I don't know a lot about this, but something in the workflow is causing this "standby" memory to get counted against the available physical memory, until there is none left.

Comment: Another idea is that these PNGs are being retained via SuperFetch. However, I'm not sure why they would be used by SuperFetch in the mode where a parent C++ application calls for their creation, and not in the mode where a BAT file drives.

Comment: Can you temporarily disable SuperFetch and retry?

Comment: I did, and no dice. I also did a run where I retained the frame extraction call to ffmpeg, but commented out the copy to the final destination directories, and there was no memory climb. So something in the copying is causing the issue. In looking around, there seem to be reports of large amounts of file copies causing cached memory to stick around. Looking into that now...

Comment: That's interesting. Are you doing copying programatically, or from a batch file?

Comment: Programatically via a system() call to DOS copy. Trying xcopy now to see if there is any difference. Archaic approach, but I would switch to something a little more robust or beefy (createProcess, boost, etc) if I actually thought it would make a difference. I don't...